# WebView not Loading Data?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to load the parsed html data from an rss feed using a
WebView, but the webview claims that the page:

"data:text/html;utf-8,[The html I'm trying to display]"

is not available.

[image]

I find it strange that it seems to be putting the html data into the
url, when I just want it to display it.

Here's my code right now for the webview:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);

webview.loadData(data.getString("DEFAULTTEXT"), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Where the HTML has been passed in a string in the Bundle with the
identifier: DEFAULTTEXT. I've tested the class and the HTML is passed
fine, it just isn't displayed correctly.

It works fine on some of the webpages I've tried, but not others. I'll try to post the code of one that works and one that doesn't.

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm reading in to a java string and it doesn't display. But when I copy and paste into a .html file which I open using the file:///assets/my.html url, it opens fine. So I know it can render the html, but it doesn't like it when it's in my generated string.

Comment: Same problem here, some pages work, some not...

Comment: Actually, loadDataWithBaseURL solved the problem.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't fixed this yet. I'll try that.

Comment: Worked for me too, was getting error with loadData, now using something like this : webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",resultData.getString(MarketRules.MARKET_RULES), "text/html", "utf-8", ""); and it's good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huuu.... so I turned my computer on this morning and it worked perfectly. I still don't know what the problem was. :/

Edit: Never mind. It works on some, but not all of the pages I try to display.

Edit2: swapping it out for loadDataWithBaseURL worked like a charm.

Comment: Mine worked across the board and then stopped working for everything one day.  loadDataWithBaseURL works for now, hope it doesn't break as mysteriously

Answer (score 2):

As stated, when you have characters like '%', '\', '#' in your HTML, it needs to be escaped which loadData doesn't seem to do automatically.

[loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of loadData does escape and seems to fix this. Just use null for baseUrl and historyUrl. So the example code in the question is changed to:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,data.getString("DEFAULTTEXT"), "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this sporadic behavior of loadData* is because of what is the content of the page you are trying to load. If it is plain simple html it has no problem. But if it has components like css or other features requiring external info, it will bail out.
My experience!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct permissions defined in the manifest.xml?

Comment: I have internet permissions, audio state, and phone state is there another one I'd need?